# mongodb/javascript: Group data by date, perform operations on it and then display it

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is a sample JSON object, among 1000 like them, stored in my MongoDB collection.

`{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b1bb74ffc7ee601c6915939"),
  "groupId": "-abcde",
  "applicationId": "avcvcvc",
  "integration": "web",
  "Category": "message",
  "Action": "message",
  "Type": "newMessage",
  "Id": "activity",
  "data": {
    "test": "good morning"
  },
  "timestamp": 1528543055858.0,
  "createdAt": ISODate("2018-06-09T11:17:35.868+0000"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2018-06-09T11:17:35.868+0000"),
  "__v": NumberInt(0)
}`

This object is an example of data with date as 2018-06-09. There are objects with successive dates in db. I have to fetch data with a specific date and perform this operation on all objects with that date

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      $or: [{
          Type: "on mouse hover click"
        }, {
          Type: "on mouse out"
        },
        {
          Type: "on chat start"
        }, {
          Type: "Load Event"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

The api, when called, should show a specific date and the calculation performed in the upper query alongwith it. this should happen on all objects with diff. dates. For this, i have made a sample schema

```js
let { Schema } = require("mongoose");
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

let dataSchema = Schema({
    date: { type: Date },
    calculation: { type: Number }
});

let NewData = mongoose.model('dataSchema', dataSchema);
module.exports = { NewData };
```

How can i achieve this? I am new to MongoDB so i cant quite figure out how to do this.

Comment: Did you get correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot group by a date cause are differents minutes seconds millis etc etc

you need make a project for date instead datetime, those can have same date but different time
Then you can perform grouping and what you want to do

```
db.getCollection("collection")
  .aggregate([
    {
      $project : {
        "groupId":1,
        "applicationId":1,
        "integration":1,
        "Category":1,
        "Action":1,
        "Type":1,
        "Id":1,
        "data":1,
        "timestamp":1,
        "createdAt":1,
        "updatedAt":1,
        "__v":1
        createdDate: { $dateToString: {format: "%G-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt"}},
      }
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: "$createdDate", count: { $sum: 1 } },

    }
  ]);
```